# How to recover PPPoE password from Netgear N600?

Tags: router, dsl

I have a Netgear N600 wireless router. How can I recover my PPPoE from that device? The web interface only shows dots for the password...

Comment: You probably can't from the router itself, but you might be able to from the web browser if it was saved in the browser. What web browser are you using?

Comment: In Configuration of router, under Maintenance -> select Backup Settings. Create a backup, open it in texteditor (e.g. notepad) and try to find user name for PPPoE, near could be a password.

Comment: Does the HTML source reveal any value for the password field?

Comment: @gertvdijk yes, it does indeed! :)

Comment: @week The config seems encrypted, I cannot even find the username. But gertvdijk's hint worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the HTML source of the web interface provides the information, even when some display setting hides it. Sometimes it's not that easy, but for most devices I've seen, passwords are just in the source and can be found like this.

An example for an OpenWRT-enabled device here:

[image]

Right-click -> View source -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> -> "password"

```
<input type="password" [...] value="p4ssw0rdp4ssw0rd" />
```